# Why isn't the "at" command sending data to the designated output file?

Tags: bash, at-job

I am trying to use the "at" command to run a lengthy code (code.x) that will take values from an input deck (input_deck.in) and output the results to results.out. I have a text file labeled job.txt with the desired command. The contents of job.txt are as follows.

```
    ./code.x<input_deck.in>results.out
```

In the terminal I have

```
    at -M -f job.txt now
```

The results.out file gets created but no output is sent to it. I am trying to understand the reason why, and how to make it so that the output gets sent to that file.

Thank you,

Kyle

Comment: Try `./code.x input_deck.in > results.out`?

Comment: I suggest to use full path to `code.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code.x does not have execute permission.

Add `2>error.log` to the end of command, run `at` and then check error.log to see what is really going on.

```sh
# job.txt
./code.x < input_deck.in > results.out 2> error.log

# terminal
at -M -f job.txt now
cat error.log
```

You can remove `2>error.log` after the problem being solved.